# C# - Why is my wrapper function for error handling not catching exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, error-handling, wrapper

I am using the following to generically wrap functionality:

```
public static class ErrorHandling
{
    public static void TryCatchErrors<TLogger>(ILogger<TLogger> logger, Action action, string? customMsg = null) => TryCatchErrors<TLogger, object>(logger, () => { action.Invoke(); return 0; }, customMsg);
    public static TOut TryCatchErrors<TLogger, TOut>(ILogger<TLogger> logger, Func<TOut> action, string? customMsg = null)
    {
        try 
        {
            if (logger == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException($"Got null for logger", $"Expected type ILogger<{typeof(TLogger).AssemblyQualifiedName}>!"); }
            if (action == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException($"Got null for action", $"Expected type Func<{typeof(TOut).AssemblyQualifiedName}>!"); }
            return action.Invoke(); 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.LogError(e, customMsg ?? e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute the following example of my intended usage of the above, my wrapper function fails to catch the error:

```
    public static async Task DeleteRecords<TLog>(ILogger<TLog> _logger) =>
        await ErrorHandling.TryCatchErrors(_logger, async () =>
        {
            // Other functionality that might throw an unexpected error etc.

            throw new Exception();
        });
```

While the potential for me to just be missing something stupid here is definitely real, I get the impression that this is related to some lower-level issue or concern that I'm not aware of & have struggled to figure out myself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the first method won't compile, you are catching the exception, but you must return something.

Comment: Why would you catch the exception there, even when you are not able to solve it. (for example return anything useful) Catch exceptions when you are able to solve them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are returning the task returned from the parameter `Func<TOut> action` directly. Meaning that the Task might not be executed inside the try/catch in TryCatchErrors. At the moment it only works as a proxy by passing the task to it's caller.

Make it async and await it there. By making it async and await it inside the method, you're are making it part of the statemachine. So the try/catch will be part of it also.

```
public async static TOut TryCatchErrors<TLogger, TOut>(ILogger<TLogger> logger, Func<TOut> action, string? customMsg = null)
{
    try 
    {
        if (logger == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException($"Got null for logger", $"Expected type ILogger<{typeof(TLogger).AssemblyQualifiedName}>!"); }
        if (action == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException($"Got null for action", $"Expected type Func<{typeof(TOut).AssemblyQualifiedName}>!"); }
        await action.Invoke(); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.LogError(e, customMsg ?? e.Message);
    }
}
```

I didn't test it, but I think you should change the methods signature to:

```
public async static Task<TOut> TryCatchErrors<TLogger, TOut>(ILogger<TLogger> logger, Func<Task<TOut>> action, string? customMsg = null)
{
    try 
    {
        if (logger == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException($"Got null for logger", $"Expected type ILogger<{typeof(TLogger).AssemblyQualifiedName}>!"); }
        if (action == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException($"Got null for action", $"Expected type Func<{typeof(TOut).AssemblyQualifiedName}>!"); }
        await action.Invoke(); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.LogError(e, customMsg ?? e.Message);
    }
}
```

else you're probably not allowed to await it.

Comment: Probably rename the new async signature to TryCatchErrorsAsync, to follow .NET idioms.

Comment: I'm curious when they drop the async postfix. It's cluttering the code.